# Does positive Yamabe invariant imply every metric in that conformal class has positive scalar curvature?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, conformal-geometry

Here I'm taking the Yamabe invariant of $(M,g)$ to mean the conformal invariant $Y(g)$ as given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yamabe_invariant), not the supremum $\sigma(M)$ over all metrics $g$ (which is also sometimes called the Yamabe invariant). I feel like my lack of visualisation of conformal changes of metric is stopping me from answering what might be a very basic question:

Given a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ of dimension $\geq 3$, with $Y(g)>0$, does every metric in the conformal class of $g$ (i.e. those metrics $e^{2f}g$ for smooth functions $f$) have everywhere positive scalar curvature? $(*)$

In other words (by the Yamabe problem), if $(M,g)$ admits a conformal metric of constant positive scalar curvature, does every conformal metric have positive scalar curvature? As a potential counterexample, could one find a metric conformal to the standard metric on the sphere which has non-positive scalar curvature somewhere?

If the answer to $(*)$ is no, could there exist a metric in the conformal class of $g$ with everywhere negative scalar curvature?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $\tilde g = e^{2 \varphi}g $ are conformally related metrics, the corresponding scalar curvatures are related by the transformation law $$\tilde S  = e^{-2\varphi}\left(S + 2(n-1)\Delta_g\varphi - (n-2)(n-1)|\nabla\varphi|_g^2\right).\tag 1 $$

Thus the fact that $g$ has (e.g.) $S=1$ places no pointwise constraint on $\tilde S$: constructing a smooth function $\varphi$ to have a local maximum of $1$ at $p$ but very quickly fall nearby, we can make $\tilde S(p)$ negative with arbitrarily large magnitude. Thus the answer to $(*)$ is no.

The answer to your followup question, however, might be more satisfying: If $S\ge 0$ everywhere and $\varphi$ attains its minimum at some point $p$ (e.g. if $M$ is compact), then at $p$ we have (again from $(1)$) $$\tilde S = e^{-2 \varphi}(S + 2(n-1)\Delta_g \varphi) \ge  e^{-2 \varphi} S \ge 0,$$
so at least in the compact case, a metric with (everywhere) positive scalar curvature cannot be conformally related to one with (everywhere) negative scalar curvature.

Comment: In the second paragraph, you only use that $p$ is a local minimum right? If I'm not mistaken, there is no additional information to be gained from knowing that $p$ is a global minimum.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: yes, that's right.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis: Apologies for a reply (almost exactly!) 3 years later. You say you construct a smooth function $\varphi$ to have a local maximum of 1. Are you meaning this function $\varphi$ gives us a local maximum (say $\varphi_{max}$) for its corresponding scalar curvature $S$? If so, are you viewing $S$ as a functional of $\varphi$, say $S= F(\varphi)$, and actually giving a local maximum for this functional? Then saying that we can construct $F$ such that $F(\varphi)$ falls arbitrarily fast either side of $\varphi_{max}$?

Comment: @JMill: nothing so abstract - I just mean that the smooth function itself $\varphi : M \to \mathbb R$ attains a local maximum at the point $p,$ i.e. $\varphi(p) > \varphi(x)$ for nearby $x$.